# Growth Rate of the Square-Free Part

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, square-free

In the course of considering [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/296729/solve-this-diophantine-equations-2x-13y-1-2z2) Diophantine equation, I convinced myself that the following question is interesting:

> If $n$ is large, must it be the case that the square-free part of $2^n-1$ is also large?

Let me elaborate on the setup of the question to remove any ambiguities.

Recall the fact that every natural number $n$ can be written uniquely as the product of some square-free number $k$ and some square $m^2$, i.e. $n=km^2$ where $p|k\Rightarrow p||k$.

(The following notation is not standard, but can be found at least on Wikipedia.)

Since every natural can be factored uniquely in this way, we can define a function sending naturals to their square-free parts. Define $\text{core}_2(n)=k$ when $n=km^2$ is the factorization into square-free and square parts. The question posed at the beginning of the post can now be rephrased as:

> Is it true that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\text{core}_2(2^n-1)=\infty$?

To the best of my knowledge this is an open problem. Experimental evidence suggests that it should be true; it actually looks like $2^n-1$ itself should be square-free infinitely often, as shown by the following low quality graph:

[Graph of ln(core_2(2^n-1))](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mOUlc.jpg)

It is also easy enough to prove that there is a subsequence whose square-free parts grow without bound ($2^{2^n}-1$ suffices for this), so we can say that the $\limsup \text{core}_2(2^n-1)$ tends towards infinty. But a simple proof for the $\liminf \text{core}_2(2^n-1)$ seems harder.

My two questions for you are as follows:

1) Does anyone know of a general theory or collection of results that can give us control over the square-free parts of integer sequences defined by an expression containing an exponential term? Everything I have managed to find is rather ad hoc or specifically about polynomial values.

2) Does anyone have a nice and simple argument to turn my factoid into a proper fact?

EDIT: Major revisions to the statement of the problem for the sake of clarification. Apologies to anyone who spent time thinking in a different direction than intended.

EDIT 2: As per the comments of Wojowu and Pasten, the full strength $abc$ conjecture is enough to resolve this question (as well as generalizations to other bases besides $2$). As per Gerry Myerson's comment, I have accidentally re-asked a question that has already been resolved on this site! You may find the relevant question and answer [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/149511/squarefree-parts-of-mersenne-numbers).

Comment: $2^n-1$ will be squarefree whenever $n$ is not divisible by $\text{ord}_{p^2}(2)$ for $p$ an odd prime. I would guess you can do some approximations with replacing $2$ with an arbitrary unit mod $p^2$ which is not $1$ mod $p$.

Comment: This is _very_ closely related to the $abc$ conjecture (for $a=2^n-1,b=1,c=2^n$). This gives very strong conditional lower bounds. I don't know much about unconditional bounds, but just showing that the squarefree parts go to infinity might have been proven.

Comment: @Wojowu I'm not sure how to use the conclusion of the $abc$ conjecture to get at the lower bounds you are describing; can you elaborate on how the radical of $abc$ (which is really just the radical of $a$) can tell us about the square-free part of $a$?

Comment: The crux is that in this case, the radical of $abc$ is just twice the radical of $a$.

Comment: @Wojowu Right, but won't that pick up all of the prime divisors? Not just the primes which divide an odd number of times? I'm afraid I will have to edit my post to make clear what I mean by the square-free part...

Comment: Yes, that sounds like a good idea - I've thought squarefree part and radical are the same... either way, abc should let one show that primes with exponent 1 should be prevalent, but that is less straightforward. I'll try to give more details tomorrow.

Comment: $rad(n)^2\le sqf(n).n$

Comment: Previous question on this topic: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/149511/squarefree-parts-of-mersenne-numbers See also https://mathoverflow.net/questions/203502/squarefree-part-of-a-mersenne-number although that one is just about $2^p-1$, $p$ prime.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Oh my! I'm sorry, I did not stumble across that before posting. My apologies.